# Cannot access property spatialindextype

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, spatial

I'm using SQL Server 2008, and I go to try and script one of my tables, I get the error "Cannot access property SpatialIndexType This is not available in Sql Server 2005". Trouble is, I'm using 2008.

I have no idea what this means. I just want to script the table so I can create it in a dev database without having to add all the columns by hand. Most of the other tables in my database script just fine.

Comment: Five minutes and no answer?? Its a stack overflow record!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the 2008 Management Studio, but connecting to a 2005 database?

Answer (score 0):

Check the compatibility level of the database you are working with.  Database properties, Options.